# How to trigger mouse and keyboard event programmatically in Windows 8?

Tags: c++, windows, mouse, dispatchevent

I am trying to develop a program so that I could use my android phone as mouse. For that i will have a service running on Windows pc which will wait for packets from android phone through socket connection. These packets will contain information about the mouse events like button pressed, position etc. I want to dispatch the event in the system. How would I do that using C/C++? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've seen api for it in c# check out msdn shouldn't be hard to find

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`SendInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) function to generate simulated keyboard and mouse events.

If you are going to create an actual [NT service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681921(v=vs.85).aspx) then you might have a problem because the service will be running in the wrong session. If you still feel you need a service then you might have to spawn a new process that runs as the user in each session with `CreateProcessAsUser` but it is much simpler just to design it as a normal program that starts when a user logs in by adding a [Run registry entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx).